# How to create vm with libvirt-go package - get boot error

Tags: centos7, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I would like to create a new centos 7 vm with [kickstart](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-file.html) option over the golang library [libvirt-go](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go).

To create the new vm I need a XML-Config which I generate over the [libvirt-go-xml](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go-xml) package.

Here is my function to generate a domain struct which I parse later into a XML-Dom.

```
func defineDomain(domainName string, vcpu *libvirtxml.DomainVCPU, disks []libvirtxml.DomainDisk, interfaces []libvirtxml.DomainInterface, memory *libvirtxml.DomainMemory) *libvirtxml.Domain {
  domainId := 10

  domain := &libvirtxml.Domain{
    XMLName: xml.Name{
      Space: "Hello",
      Local: "World",
    },
    Type:        "kvm",
    ID:          &domainId,
    Name:        domainName,
    UUID:        uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4()).String(),
    Title:       domainName,
    Description: domainName,
    Metadata: &libvirtxml.DomainMetadata{
      XML: "",
    },
    Memory: memory,
    VCPU:   vcpu,
    OS: &libvirtxml.DomainOS{
      BootDevices: []libvirtxml.DomainBootDevice{
        libvirtxml.DomainBootDevice{
          Dev: "hd",
        },
      },
      Kernel:  "",
      Initrd:  "/home/markus/workspace/worker-management/centos/kvm-centos.ks",
      Cmdline: "ks=file:/home/markus/workspace/worker-management/centos/kvm-centos.ks method=http://repo02.agfa.be/CentOS/7/os/x86_64/",
      Type: &libvirtxml.DomainOSType{
        Arch: "x86_64",
        Type: "hvm",
      },
    },
    OnCrash:    "restart",
    OnPoweroff: "destroy",
    OnReboot:   "restart",
    Devices: &libvirtxml.DomainDeviceList{
      Emulator:   "/usr/bin/kvm-spice",
      Disks:      disks,
      Interfaces: interfaces,
      Graphics: []libvirtxml.DomainGraphic{
        libvirtxml.DomainGraphic{
          VNC: &libvirtxml.DomainGraphicVNC{
            AutoPort: "yes",
            Listen:   "127.0.0.1",
            Keymap:   "de",
            Listeners: []libvirtxml.DomainGraphicListener{
              libvirtxml.DomainGraphicListener{
                Address: &libvirtxml.DomainGraphicListenerAddress{
                  Address: "127.0.0.1",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }

  return domain

}
```

When I want to create the new vm with my XML-Dom, I get the following error.
`2018/09/25 08:12:45 virError(Code=1, Domain=10, Message='internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2018-09-25T06:12:45.683418Z qemu-system-x86_64: -append only allowed with -kernel option')`

I defined an empty string as Kernel option, because I don't know what to show off.

- What exactly do I need to specify under kernel option for my VM to boot properly and
- where can I find good documentation about setting the kernel option?

Answer (score 1):

You've provided a wrong `Initrd`:

```
      Initrd:  "/home/markus/workspace/worker-management/centos/kvm-centos.ks",
```

This is not an initrd, but your kickstart file (which you correctly specified in `Cmdline`.

Specifying `Kernel` and `Initrd` is not recommended. This is intended for booting a VM from a kernel which is outside the VM instance itself. In almost all circumstances, you do not want this.

Instead, this should also be the empty string, the same as `Kernel`. The VM will then boot from the virtual boot media (hard drive, ISO image, etc.) that you will provide.